# How do I add a calendar properly in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to add a calendar to my Default.aspx. How is this done? My first try was:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">

<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="Default" ID="full" Title="loc:full" WebPartVerbRenderMode="TitleBar">
    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
        ListUrl="Lists/Calendar"
        IsIncluded="True"
        JsLink="clientTemplate.js"
        NoDefaultStyle="TRUE"
        PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
        Default="False"
        ViewContentTypeId="0x">
    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

However this way causes my calendar to come out a jumbled mess. How can I properly add a calendar to my Default.aspx? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want it to be in calendar view, right?

Comment: yes! I do not know how @SergeiSergeev